amazon state language get json object value
I'm using States.StringToJson to register some raw JSON string to a JSON object, but I'd like to access an element of the JSON object to do further manipulation in that same line. Is this possible without linking several states together?
I'm hoping to do something like:
"val.$": "States.StringToJson($.Input).keyOfJSON)"

You're going to be basically limited to using intrinsic functions so it depends on what sort of manipulation you need to do. For more complex tasks, you may need to resort to using a small lambda function.
